# How to change column names in pandas Dataframe using a list of names?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been trying to change the column names of a pandas dataframe using a list of names. The following code is being used:

```
df.rename(columns = list_of_names, inplace=True)
```

However I got a Type Error each time, with an error message that says "**list object is not callable**".
  I would like to know why does this happen? And What can I do to solve this problem? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share what `list_of_names` you passed.

Comment: You might need to share more of your code to uncover the TypeError.  I suspect it's not related to this line of code.  The stack trace might also help.

Comment: @JGC i got the answer. I have used a scalar( a list) instead of a dict to change the names. Apparently it changes the series.names.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

you could use

```
df.columns = ['Leader', 'Time', 'Score']
```

Comment: when I used df.rename(column = list_of_name) , I got an error. Which I mentioned in the original question. Why does   my original code generate an error?

Comment: because when you pass a list(a scalar) to rename function,it will alter Series.name attribute. You need to pass a dict to rename to change axis values (column values)

Answer (score 13):

If you need `rename` (`l` is your list of name need to change to)

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns,l)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gives me proper insight. Could you explain why does the documnet (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) says I can use 'list-like' and 'dict-like' for 'column' . So it means i can use a list too, right? in addition to dict.

Comment: because when you pass a list(a scalar) to rename function,it will alter Series.name attribute. You need to pass a dict to rename to change axis values (column values)

Comment: @koliyat9811 you can check  Prakash's comment

Comment: this is an excellent approach! love it.

Answer (score 7):

### [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html)

To set column names, use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html) along `axis=1` or `axis='columns'`:

```
df = df.set_axis(list_of_names, axis=1)
```

Note that the default `axis=0` sets index names.

---

#### Why not just modify `df.columns` directly?

The accepted answer is fine and is used often, but [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html) has some advantages:

1. [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html) allows method chaining:

   ```
   df.some_method().set_axis(list_of_names, axis=1).another_method()
   ```

   vs:

   ```
   df = df.some_method()
   df.columns = list_of_names
   df.another_method()
   ```
2. [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html) should theoretically provide better error checking than directly modifying an attribute, though I can't find a specific example at the moment.

Comment: @MustafaAydın ah thanks, you're right. `axis=1` raises an error, but it seems `axis=0` still allows you to set a longer list as the index.

Comment: I see; but both `df.columns = ...` and `df.index = ...` errs with a length mismatch when I run. Version difference I guess. Thanks for the answer by the way, method chaining is very useful IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

Just update the columns attribute:

```
df.columns = list_of_names
```

Answer (score 1):

if your list is : column_list so `column_list` is `['a', 'b', 'c']`

and original `df.columns` is `['X', 'Y', 'Z']`

you just need: `df.columns = column_list`